# Combining Oauth2 with formlogin and actuator security in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.9 and have an application that has an API that uses OAuth2 client credentials, with formlogin for a CMS that uses Thymeleaf in the same Spring Boot application.

For this to work, I have the following bean to configure the form login:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityGlobalConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
           .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            // api security is handled elsewhere (See OAuth2ServerConfiguration)
            .antMatchers("/api/**", "/oauth/**", "/management/**")
            .permitAll()
            // end api security
            .anyRequest().hasRole(UserRole.ADMIN.name())
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll();
    }
}
```

So for the form login part, I declare everything related to API, Oauth and /management (the custom context-path I have set in `application.properties` for the actuator endpoints):

```
management.context-path=/management
management.security.roles=ADMIN
```

For Oauth2, I have this:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "my-app-service";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
            resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/api/**")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .antMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/management/health", "/management/info").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/management/**").hasRole(UserRole.ADMIN.name())
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Autowired
        private SecurityConfiguration securityConfiguration;

        // NOTE: If you set a new validity, you need to clear the 'oauth_access_token' table
        // in the database. Only new tokens get the new validity.
        @Value("${myapp.security.oauth.access-token-validity-seconds:43200}") // 12 hours by default
        private int accessTokenValiditySeconds;

        @Value("${myapp.security.oauth.refresh-token-validity-seconds:2592000}") // 30 days by default
        private int refreshTokenValiditySeconds;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
            security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                   .withClient(securityConfiguration.getMobileAppClientId())
                   .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                   .scopes("mobile_app")
                   .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                   .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValiditySeconds)
                   .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(refreshTokenValiditySeconds)
                   .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(securityConfiguration.getMobileAppClientSecret()));
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).
                    authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                     .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        }
    }
}
```

I want the following behaviour:

- If user has role `ADMIN` by using an Oauth2 access token, all actuator endpoints must be accessible
- If the user does not have this `ADMIN` role, only `/health` and `/info` should be accessible (If `ADMIN`, `/health` should show extra info like it is by default)

The current behaviour:

The info and health endpoints can be viewed by everybody, but as ADMIN, you don't get extra info. For the other endpoints, I get a 401 if I try with an access token of an ADMIN user with:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-01-30T13:45:26.625+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource.",
    "path": "/management/beans"
}
```

If I set `management.security.enabled=false` then the ADMIN user has access, but all non-ADMIN users also have access.

What should I change to get the wanted behaviour?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe. The task can be accomplish by introducing of 2 security chains. Please take a look at the following article http://blog.florian-hopf.de/2017/08/spring-security.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to make it work with the following in the `configure` method of `ResourceServerConfiguration` :

```
http
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/api/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/api/**")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/api/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .and()
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/management/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/management/health", "/management/info").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/management/**").hasRole(UserRole.ADMIN.name())
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
```

Using multiple `antMatchers` directly on the `http` object does not work, you need to first use `requestMatchers`